# iOS to execute a callback on a modified object in memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, callback, asynccallback

I am not sure if this is even possible within the realm of iOS and Objective-C, but, being able to do this would simplify so so much...

I would like to be able to execute one (or more) actions called by @selector or similar way, whenever an NSObject is modified in memory.  An alternative to a callback, is a polling mechanism via a timed thread, but this seems excessive and inefficient.

I have not been able to find answers or examples to anything like this yet, but, there may be someone who knows for sure.

Comment: Perhaps KVO is what you are looking for? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Oh, that looks really good, thank you..  At first look, it reminds me of "Observer/Observable" mechanism in Java..